# How to check whether or not a Django form is correctly bound?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

## Situation

---

Using Django 1.5, I am using `forms.ModelForm`s to let the user edit database contents. However I can't get the form to update the database upon `form.save()`.

Each of my models correspond to a setting form (the application is a the direct porting of a desktop software in which the user can store several settings). I needed to implement a *Reset to default* feature, so I thought of having a default object (imported with Django fixtures) which I would use only to reset a second one. The user would only interact with the second model.

- `pk=1` refers to the base object
- `pk=2` refers to the custom object

I have several forms on the same page (only `foobar` here), so basically this what I planned to do:

- No POST data

  1. Building form from either `pk=1` or `pk=2`, depending `pk=2` has been found or not
  2. Rendering the forms to the template
- AJAX request, with POST datas

  1. Getting form content
  2. Checking whether or not the user has permission to edit the model (checksum)
  3. Update the model form POST datas
  4. Returning AJAX response

## Code

---

I have put two debug `print`s to illustrate the issue I am facing. The form I fetch doesn't seem to be bound to my model.

```py
# Response codes to use in the template
RESPONSES = {
    200: {'code':'0xB16B00B5', 'message':'Success'},
    400: {'code':'0x8BADF00D', 'message':'Form is not valid'},
    403: {'code':'0xBAADF00D', 'message':'No permission to edit the database'},
    501: {'code':'0xDEADC0DE', 'message':'POST datas not found'},
    }

# Those are the setting labels
TYPES = {
    'foobar': {'model':FooBar, 'form':FooBarForm },
    }
```

```py
def index(request):
    # Handling form datas
    if request.method == 'POST':
        response = HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps({'code':RESPONSES[501]['code']}), 'application/json')
        for label in TYPES:

            # Filtering the right form to handle
            if label in request.POST:
                model = _fetch_setting(label, mode='model')
                form = _fetch_setting(label, mode='form', post=request.POST)
                checksum = model.checksum  # Somehow, 'form.is_valid()' is altering 'model', need to backup the checksum
                if form.is_valid():

                    # The user has permission to edit the model
                    if form.cleaned_data['checksum'] == checksum:
                        if form.has_changed():
                            print form.cleaned_data['foo']  # Outputs the form data, as expected
                            form.save()
                            print model.foo  # Outputs the old data
                            model.checksum = str(uuid4()).replace('-', '')
                            model.save()
                        response = HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps({'code':RESPONSES[200]['code']}), 'application/json')

                    # This one does not
                    else:
                        response = HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps({'code':RESPONSES[403]['code']}), 'application/json')

                    break  # We are still inside the label loop

                # The form is not valid
                else:
                    response = HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps({'code':RESPONSES[400]['code']}), 'application/json')

    # Form not submitted yet, building the HTML forms
    else:
        forms = {}
        label = 'foobar'
        for label in TYPES:
            forms[label] = _fetch_setting(label, mode='form')
        context = {'errors':RESPONSES, 'forms':forms}
        response = render(request, 'home/index.html', context)

    return response
```

```py
# Return a setting object (model or form) corresponding to the given label
def _fetch_setting(label, mode='model', post=None):
    try:
        result = None
        default = TYPES[label]['model'].objects.get(pk=1)
        try:
            model = TYPES[label]['model'].objects.get(pk=2)
        except TYPES[label]['model'].DoesNotExist:
            model = TYPES[label]['model'].objects.create(
                checksum = default.checksum,
                foo      = default.foo,
                bar      = default.bar,
                )
        if mode == 'model':
            result = model
        if mode == 'form':
            print model
            result = TYPES[label]['form'](data=post, instance=model)  # The 'instance' attribute doesn't seem to be applied
    except KeyError:
        result = None
    finally:
        return result
```

## Update

---

### 07.10

It does work when I pass the instance to bound with to `_fetch_setting`. So I guess this issue is coming from the form validation.

```py
def _fetch_setting(label, mode='model', post=None, instance=None):
    # ...
        if mode == 'form':
            if instance:
                model = instance
            result = TYPES[label]['form'](data=post, instance=model)
    # ...
```

As I commented in my code, `form.is_valid()` seems to alter the object.

Will flag as answered if no one come with a clean solution.

Comment: It all looks good. I would just change `result = TYPES[label]['form'](data=post, instance=model)` to `result = TYPES[label]['form'](post, instance=model)`

Comment: Also, `form.is_valid() seems to alter the object.` - are you doing something in the `clean` methods of the model form ? I dont believe that is the actual cause of error though

Comment: @karthikr, Is there a particular reason not to specify optionnal parameters ? I'm a little fussy ;].

Comment: @karthikr, No the `clean` methods are not overwritten (if this is what you meant). Updated the question.

Comment: I was just thinking `data=post` vs just `post` would make a difference.

Comment: @karthikr, Nope I added `data=` when facing my issue. Was looking for everything that could possibly remotely fix the thing ;].

Comment: Is `form.save()` creating a new model object every time? If not you probably are looking for `model= form.save()`

Comment: @karthikr, I think I start to understand what's going on... Indeed the `form.save()` line should be interpreted to update only and not to create. What I don't understand is, why should it fix my issue (aka. not modifying my `model`) since I am not using the variable anymore after the `save` call ?

Comment: because. a model forms' `form.save()` returns the model object with the saved data. You might be looking for `model = form.save(commit=False)` - That would put things more into perspective for you

Comment: @karthikr, +1 for the `commit=False`. Completely forgot this, this will look way more natural in my view. Feel free to write an actual answer ;].

Comment: will do once you confirm this fixed the issue :)

Comment: @karthikr, Yup fixed !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is, you are creating a new model object with each `form.save()`

You need to update the same model object with `commit=False`

```py
if form.cleaned_data['checksum'] == checksum:
    if form.has_changed():
        print form.cleaned_data['foo']  # Outputs the form data, as expected
        model = form.save(commit=False)
        model.checksum = str(uuid4()).replace('-', '')
        model.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

From the fabulous manual:

> The first time you call `is_valid()` or access the errors attribute of a `ModelForm` triggers form validation as well as model validation. This has the side-effect of cleaning the model you pass to the ModelForm constructor. For instance, calling `is_valid()` on your form will convert any date fields on your model to actual date objects. If form validation fails, only some of the updates may be applied. For this reason, you’ll probably want to avoid reusing the model instance passed to the form, especially if validation fails.